# Django Checkbox with multiple options to choose from

Tags: django, django-models

I am trying to make a field in my Django Admin Model to have a checkbox. But instead of one box (True/False) I would like to have 3 different options.

```
Label:   [] Option1
         [] Option2
         [] Option3
```

Not a multi select. As I should only be able to select one of these.

EDIT:

```
models.py
```

This is what I have in my model.

```
required = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

But this only gives me one checkbox. I would like to have 3 different options to choose from.

Answer (score 0):

take this example of how to impement radio select in form :)

```
from django import forms

OPTIONS= [
    ('Option1', '1'),
    ('Option2', '2'),
    ('Option3', '3'),
    ('Option4', '4'),
    ]

class UserForm(forms.Form):
    opts= forms.CharField(label='Label:', widget=forms.RadioSelect(choices=OPTIONS))
```

Comment: what do you mean by model? in Django, models are defining the DB structure. Forms are created in separeted fife forms.py

Comment: Yeah your solution appears to be using forms? I need it a field within my model.

Comment: sorry I dont understand your question.. You are trying to make a form to render on html page where user can check one of the options right? If not, can you please describe what exactly do you want and show what have you tried? Maybe your code will help us to understand your problem

Comment: edited it. The answer could still be in the forms. I am new to Django and no nothing about forms yet. I am just trying to use a checkbox to store 1 of 3 different options into my database model. I could do this with a multiselect, but i wanted to use check boxes.

Comment: still not enough, please post your models.py forms.py and the views.py
model is defining your DB structure, for example the table column names and types, the forms.py is defining how the form should look like and what fields it should contain, the views.py will render the form to the webpage and also recieve the input from the webpage(in this case what option is choosed) and it will store it into DB table. I hope its more understandable how the Django works now?

Comment: Also I recommend reading the official documentation to Django, it will take some time, but its very helpful and it will answer most of your questions, I am sure you could solve this problem easily after reading the docs. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/